# Search ListView and then Update the ListView with the results

Tags: c#, listview, search

I am having some troubles being able to search a listview I have. Basically I am making a music player where all the metadata is added to the listview. Then I want to be able to have a search where it will search all the different columns for the what the user wants.

So basically below is an example of my listview and its data. If you were to type in 'Cr' as in the example and click OK then the list should update so that only the rows with the Title 'Cryin' and 'Crazy' would show. However when you then delete the search bar so its blank all the list items should reappear.

A link to an image showing my list:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ8NI.jpg

Basically the pesudo code would be something along the lines of:

```
string searchTerm

check each row to see if it contains the searchTerm

If a row does contain the searchTerm do nothing

else remove it from the list
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".